# Can I have someone else cash the stimulus check in my account?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, non-resident, check, stimulus

I have received my stimulus , but I'm living abroad. So it's been very hard to cash the check.

A friend of mine is visiting, would it be possible for that person to take the check and deposit at a bank account in my name? (I already have a us bank account, but it will not let me cash it unless I'm physically in the us).

Has anyone tried this? Will it work?
Does anyone know about this?

Also I tried remote depositing, it only works if you're inside the US (at least for my bank).

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Checks issued by the US Treasury have special rules for handling, and so your friend _might_ be able to _deposit_ your stimulus check into your _existing_ bank account by taking the check to your bank (provided that you have endorsed the check as "Deposit to Bank account # 1234567879", but won't be able to get cash for it. Of course, the bank teller might insist on the endorsement being done in front of the teller, or for _your_ ID from your friend. I don't understand what "take the cash and deposit at a bank account in my name" means. Your friend cannot _open_ an account in your name.

Comment: I meant take the check! What I want is that person to deposit the check in my bank account. I don't need the money withdrawn after that.

Comment: Can't you simply mail the check to your U.S. bank with a deposit slip?

Comment: Please **edit** your question instead of answering in the comments. Not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate I did before you posted the last comment...

Comment: @RiverNet I'm worried it might get lost...

Comment: Just use your banks app to deposit it online by taking a picture of the check. No physical movement of the check required, and no friend's account or whatever. Your friend can email you the photos of the check if he has it.

Comment: @Aganju As I said, remote depositing is not option. Capital One will not allow remote depositing outside of the US.

Comment: Use a VPN. It makes you look as being in the US.

Comment: Then send it certified mail.  If mailing the check is the easiest option (since it doesn't require having to ask, trust, or involve anyone else) then that's that way to go, IMHO.  You can find a flaw or "worry" with any solution you come up with, but sooner or later you're going to have to do something, right?

Comment: @Aganju Already tried, but only tried protonvpn, perhaps I should try a paid option?

Comment: @RiverNet I agree, but wouldn't it be safer if someone deposited the check for me in my account? After all, government checks can't be deposited in an account not belonging to the beneficiary of the check.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - that looks like an answer to me....

Comment: Again, the EASIEST and LEAST COMPLICATED way to do this is send the check with a deposit slip, CERTIFIED MAIL, to your bank to have it deposited.  Why in the world do you need to complicate it by involving anyone else???  This seems very foolish to me.  What if THEY lose the check?

Comment: @RiverNet does Certified Mail extend across country borders?  I’m dubious.